# using pivot function in mysql to make a table apriori

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

this was almost same cases in this case [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns) but the results was different and it make me confuse.

let's say i have 3 tables

```
create table order_match
(
id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
order_status_id int(10) not null
);

create table order_match_detail
(
 id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
 order_match_id int(10) not null,
 product_id int(10) NOT NULL
);

create table product
(
id int(10) PRIMARY KEY not null,
name varchar(255) not null
);

Insert into order_match (id, order_status_id)
select 1, 6 union all
select 2, 7 union all
select 3, 6 union all
select 4, 6;

Insert into order_match_detail (id, order_match_id, product_id)
select 1, 1, 147  union all
select 2, 2, 148 union all
select 3, 3, 147 union all
select 4, 4, 149 union all
select 5, 4, 147;

Insert into product (id, name)
select 147, 'orange' union all
select 148, 'carrot' union all
select 149, 'Apple';
```

with `order_match.id = order_match_detail.order_match_id`
and `order_match_detail.product_id = product.id`

so like the previous case in [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns) i want to input the product name with the transaction in order_status_id not in 7 (because 7 is expired transaction and denied)

```
the expected results was like this :
id (in order_match)    |    Orange  |  Carrot  |   Apple

1                           1            0           0
3                           1            0           0
4                           1            0           1
```

based on solution in previous cases, i used this

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when product.name = ''',
      product.name,
      ''' then 1 end) AS ',
      replace(product.name, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from product;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT omd.order_match_id, ', @sql, ' from order_match_detail omd
left join order_match om
  on omd.order_match_id = om.id
left join product p
  on omd.product_id = p.id
where om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by omd.order_match_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

but idk why return 0 and it's no way

this is the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nDe3oQ3VdtfS5QDokieHN4/6

Comment: As already mentioned on more than one occasion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. That said , your best option (and again as already mentioned) is to handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: sorry sir, done sir @Strawberry

Comment: Add `SELECT @sql;` into your fiddle. Execute. Then copy its `FROM` section, add `SELECT *` to it and execute. Investigate the result.

Comment: *idk why return 0* Because there is no a row in `sales` with partner_id=2 and product_id=1.

Comment: im sorry sir, that's wrong fiddle

Comment: please take a look at my new fiddle, that's my real case

Answer (score 0):

For your GROUP_CONCAT query; in your case stmt, you are referring to your product table as `product` itself. But in your join query, you are referring to product table as alias `p`. Since the first group_concat query is a part of the join query, you need to keep the table aliases same.(made changes at line 5)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when p.name = ''',  
      product.name,
      ''' then 1 end) AS ',
      replace(product.name, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @pivotsql
from product;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT omd.order_match_id, ', @pivotsql, ' from order_match_detail omd
left join order_match om
  on omd.order_match_id = om.id
left join product p
  on omd.product_id = p.id
  where om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
group by omd.order_match_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```